# PHP: How to check returned value of a function in another function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return, echo

I have a function which returns a value that I'd like to check via another one. I can not echo it in the first function as far as I know, as it's used in a wordpress filter for body_class and outputted there.

So, how do I check what the returned value is in another function?

An example of the first function that returns $class, which is what I want to check:

```
function layout_class( $class ) {
    // There is lots of more functionality here for the $layout variable
    $layout = 'col-3cm';

    $class[] = $layout;
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'layout_class' );
```

Now, this class decides whether or not to load a secondary sidebar template. So I would like to do:

```
function sidebar_dual() {
    $layout = layout_class();   
    if (
        ( $layout == 'col-3cm' ) ||
        ( $layout == 'col-3cl' ) ||
        ( $layout == 'col-3cr' )
    )
    { get_template_part('sidebar-2'); }
}
```

Since I can't echo out the first function, and don't want to write another function as it is quite big - how do I approach it? Is there an easy way to check a return value, similar to echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to refactor your code.

You just need to move the code that determines the layout into a separate function that you can call both inside the filter and inside the `sidebar_dual()` function:

```
function get_layout_mode(){

   // There is lots of more functionality here for the $layout variable
   $layout = 'col-3cm';

   return $layout;
}
```

The filter function becomes:

```
function layout_class( $class ) {
    $class[] = get_layout_mode();
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'layout_class' );
```

And in your `sidebar_dual()` function call `get_layout_mode()` instead of `layout_class()`

---

It is possible to work with your current code too, by splitting the string returned by WP's [`get_body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class) function into an array then checking if any of those 3 classes are present inside the array. I would go with the first option though, because it's clearer.

Comment: Ah, of course! Didn't think of that. For your get_layout_mode(), will it still work to check for sidebar_dual() if it uses return instead of echo for $layout? Guess I'll give it a shot and see.

Comment: There's no need for echo anywhere in your code above. I'm guessing you're referring to the `body_class()` function which echoes HTML, but that doesn't interfere with your code

Comment: I thought I was unable to check a return value with a == 'something' via another function and only could check echo, as I ran into issues with return. True php newbie here though, learning by trial and failure :-)

Comment: That's probably because of the inconsistencies in WordPress. Some WP functions return values, some just echo HTML. For example `body_class()` echoes the classes, while `get_body_class()` returns an array with the classes. This may be confusing to new PHP programmers

Comment: Yeah, was confusing me. Just an update, the function now works flawlessly and I could remove tons of code. So, big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you leave `$class` empty in your `layout_class($class)` then your function is invalid anyways. You need to declare something for the variable `layout_class($class = null)` or if you call it `layout_class(null)` but if you do not declare it, it will not work as the way you have it set up is required.

The rest of your code is okay.

Also, you have declared `$class` in your function, and you are using it as a variable within the function, I would rename your output ie

```
function layout_class( $class ) {
    // There is lots of more functionality here for the $layout variable
    $layout = 'col-3cm';

    return $layout;
}
```